# Subfolder redirect in htaccess, then remove last 10 characters in a URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

We have a problem where a site is creating some weird redirect errors.
I need to rewrite the following url format

```
http://example.com/111/news/news/article-1469.html
```

to

```
http://example.com/archive/article/
```

I've got this which is working in part with this in my htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^111/news/news/(.*)$ /archive/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

it works in the most part taking people to

```
http://example.com/archive/article-1469.html
```

The problem is the last section - the '-1469.html' I need to get rid of that. The catch is that there are loads of these redirects and the numbers could be any four numbers (they're not always the same)

Is there a way to blanket remove the last 10 characters of a URL?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`RewriteRule ^111/news/news/(.*).{10}$ /archive/$1`

it looks for 10 chrs after your capture group, effectively removing the last 10 chars as you asked.

Another option is to break at the dash, although that is not what you requested:

`^111/news/news/(.*)\-.*$` 
the advantage would be if you had some numbers that were 3 or 5 digits rather than exclusively 4, however if you have some prefixes with a dash in it, then this wont work.